# I am biblical and wrathful - Who am I?

Tags: riddle

I am biblical and wrathful its true,
Unlike a certain messiah, harlots not welcome,
confessionals with me are disturbing, certainly sacrilege,
Time now lost and regretted, Carpe Diem,

Unlike your savior, Mine is of fire,
Our heaven is not perfect, Escape it,
Trumpets call numbers and all is clear

Who/What am i?

Hint:

> Numbers are all over the place in the bible: in verses(psalms 1:1), in stories (10,000 loaves of bread) and in the rules (10 commandments). They hold what you seek

Hint 2:

> 3-in-1 First Line could be a clue all its own, the remaining 6 are gathered, 7x7 the riddle unfolds

Hint 3:

> Each line has a solution and when put together create the answer. It is not straight from the bible but rather references it quite a bit

Hint 4:

> We Can't Stay Here. This is Riddle Country

Comment: In a couple of hours, If there are no attempts that show promise I will post a hint

Comment: You can give it at least half a day or so as people in the SE are form all over the world and might not even see this in the next 10 hours ;)

Comment: counting words I see 7,7,7,7: 7,7,7.

Comment: There's certainly a lot in here that's reminiscent of the Book of Revelation - the number 7 (7 seals, 7 churches, 7 angels, 7 trumpets etc.), the 'wrathful' nature, the harlot, the fire, the numbered trumpets and so on.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 The 7 upvotes?

Comment: I would upvote, but I don't want to break the seal.

Comment: @ericm301 You can upvote - it's at 8 now. :P

Comment: I have a hint that I could give that I fear would make it instantly solvable so I will continue to give cryptic hints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a stretch but are you

> Avenged Sevenfold

I am biblical and wrathful its true,

> Avenging implies wrath, Seven has a significant presence in the bible

Unlike a certain messiah, harlots not welcome,

> The song The Beast and the Harlot is about the Fall of Babylon (and the aforementioned Harlot is the Whore of Babylon)

confessionals with me are disturbing, certainly sacrilege,

> The song Unholy Confessions

Time now lost and regretted, Carpe Diem,

> The song Seize the Day, specifically the line "Seize the day or die regretting the time you lost"

Unlike your savior, Mine is of fire,

> The song Shepherd of Fire

Our heaven is not perfect, Escape it,

> The song Afterlife "I don't belong here, I gotta move on dear, escape from this afterlife"

Trumpets call numbers and all is clear

> Their debut album was titled 'Sounding the Seventh Trumpet'

Comment: After a decently long time the answer has been discovered! Congrats

Comment: Thanks, it was that fourth hint that got me thinking in the right direction.

Comment: I figured that last one might be a bit too easy but its been almost 10 days XD

Comment: Although the hint says "it is not straight from the bible", in fact those very words appear in Genesis chapter 4 (at least in some translations). (For the avoidance of doubt, this isn't a complaint, and I would be *astonished* if anyone didn't solve this who would have solved it without that remark.)